# Error in cross entropy loss calculation in keras

Tags: tensorflow, keras

I am trying to use the tf crossentropy loss function inside keras. The error is:

```
Incompatible shapes: [512,184,55] vs. [512,55]
```

loss function is:

```
def keras_binary_cross_entropy_with_logits(tgt, pred):
return tf.nn.sigmoid_cross_entropy_with_logits(labels=tgt, logits=pred)
```

The idea is to do multilabel classification where target is multilabel binarized. The y_true has shape [batch_size, label_vocab_length] and y_pred has shape [batch_size, sequnece_length, label_vocab_length]. In the example above `y_true =[512,55]` and `y_pred=[512,184,55`.

Full error

```
InvalidArgumentError: Incompatible shapes: [512,184,55] vs. [512,55]
 [[{{node training_2/RMSprop/gradients/loss_5/dense_output_loss/logistic_loss/mul_grad/BroadcastGradientArgs}} = BroadcastGradientArgs[T=DT_INT32, _class=["loc:@train...ad/Reshape"], _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0"](training_2/RMSprop/gradients/loss_5/dense_output_loss/logistic_loss/mul_grad/Shape, training_2/RMSprop/gradients/loss_5/dense_output_loss/logistic_loss/mul_grad/Shape_1)]]
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: The error is quite clear, the shapes have to be the same in order to compute the loss, either y_true should be [512, 184, 55], or y_pred should be [512, 55].

Comment: I knew that but my concern was what to do to get rid of this error. Now I figured out that I should set `return_sequences= False` so that I am using only the last hidden states for prediction. Thanks